# Is it possible to have more than one @media print in css file

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to have 2 different @page and @media print styles in one CSS file. It could be separate as well. Why I require 2 is I am printing out bar-codes and the page needs to be different sizes when printing. Currently whats happening is its using style 1 styling for both bar-codes. How do I set it were it only uses style 1 styling for **Barcode1** and style 2 for **Barcode2**.

Code:
CSS

```
**style 1**
    @page { size: 8cm 3cm; margin-top: 16px; } /* output size */
    body.receipt1 .sheet1 { width: 10cm; height: 3cm; margin-left: 35px; } /* sheet size */
    @media print { body.receipt1 { width: 3cm } } /* fix for Chrome */

**style 2**
    @page { size: 10cm 5cm; margin-top: 16px; } /* output size */
    body.receipt2 .sheet2 { width: 12cm; height: 5cm; margin-left: 35px; } /* sheet size */
    @media print { body.receipt2 { width: 5cm } } /* fix for Chrome */
```

**Barcode1**

```
<body className="receipt1">
          <section className="sheet1">
            <table className="table_b10">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td className="heading1_b10">Worksgroup</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td className="heading2_b10">SKU: {this.props.stateInfo.itemName}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td className="heading2_b10">
                  <Barcode value={this.props.stateInfo.itemName} width={1} height={30} fontSize={0} margin={0} format="CODE128" />
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td className="heading2_b10">{this.props.stateInfo.itemDescription}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td className="heading2_bb10">LOG-ID: {this.props.audit.id}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table> 
        </section>
      </body>
```

**Barcode2**

```
<body class="receipt2">
    <section class="sheet2">
          <table className="table_b5">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td className="heading1_b5">Worksgroup</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td className="heading2_b5">Job No\PO:</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td className="heading3_b5">{this.props.job.jobNumber}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td className="heading2_b5">SKU:</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td className="heading3_b5">{this.props.stateInfo.itemName}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td className="heading3_b5">
                <Barcode value={this.props.stateInfo.itemName} width={0.75} height={25} fontSize={0} margin={0} format="CODE128" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td className="heading3_b5">{this.props.stateInfo.itemDescription}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td className="heading3b_b5">LOG-ID: {this.props.audit.id}
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        </section>
      </body>
```